Why do I get a Render Error (undefined function error) when calling a method but a property is OK?
I'm relatively new to react/react-native and I think I'm doing something react doesn't like in the render, though it's not helping me understand the error.
This is an expo/react-native typescript project.
I want to define a getStartDateTime() method on CalendarEventItem because I want to refactor the startTime property to be a number instead of a Date.
Error:
Render Error: event.getStartDateTime is not a function (it is undefined)
Typescript has no complaints whatsoever, only react/react-native renderer, apparently. Accessing startTime property directly works perfectly, calling a method results in this error.
Minimum code:

Component.tsx

const Component = () => {

  const events: CalendarEventItem[] = useCalendarStore((state) => state.events); // Zustand store

  const calculatePositionOffset(startTime: Date, gap: number, rowHeight: number) => {
    return (startTime.getHours() + startTime.getMinutes() / 60) * rowHeight + gap;
  }

  return (

    {events.length &&
      events.map((event) => (

        <EventContainer
          event={event}
          position={{
            top: calculatePositionOffset(event.getStartDateTime(), 3, 30), // <-- Error occurs here
            left: 100,
          }}
          key={"event-" + event.id}
        />

     ))}

  );
}


CalendarEvent.ts

// Probably can ignore mixins, including just for completeness

abstract class CalendarEvent extends extendSchedulableItem(extendAgendaObject(class {})) {
  abstract getStartDateTime(): Date; // this is here because I ultimately want to define 
                                     // this method on a grandparent class, removing does not 
                                     // affect the error
}

class CalendarEventItem extends CalendarEvent {

  startTime: Date; // want to refactor this to number, hence the need for a method

  constructor(params) {
    super(params); // this.startTime is initialized by a grandparent constructor in SchedulableItem
  }

  getStartDateTime() {
    return new Date(this.startTime);
  }
}

export { CalendarEvent, CalendarEventItem }

The interesting part to me is that:
top: calculatePositionOffset(event.startTime, 3, 30), // <-- Works absolutely fine
top: calculatePositionOffset(event.getStartDateTime(), 3, 30), // <-- Produces the render error

What am I doing wrong?
I tried various ways to redefine the method, including in the grandparent classes and mixins. It doesn't seem to work even if simply independently defined in a final class. The AI assistant did not prove helpful in understanding or resolving the problem.
I also tried wrapping calculatePositionOffset with useCallback, in case this was more renderer-friendly, but with same ultimate result (slightly different error but stemming from undefined startTime parameter nonetheless).

So, apparently, the problem was not react/react-native but just the knowledge of much more basic JavaScript semantics.
Defining the method as an arrow function completely resolved all errors, because of the this context, whereas the arrow function retains the lexical scope of this and a regular function may retain scope depending on how its bound.
getStartDateTime = () => {
  return new Date(this.startTime);
}

The more you know!
